# Have Laravel 5.8 count data in other fields not just unsignedInteger

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Hi I am new to Laravel,

I have two database tables (boxes and items) aka a hasMany() relationship.  I am trying to get laravel to display 4 results of the **boxbarcode** column not 5 of the **box_id** as you see in the screenshot. Basically, all items that are of box TRTB0001

The problem is it is looking at the **box_id** (1,1,1,1,1) not the **boxbarcode** (TRTB0001). How can I adjust my Model, Controller, View to display this?  See code below.

**Box.php (Model)**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Box extends Model
{

    protected $guarded = [];


    public function items(){

        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }

}
```

**Item.php (Model)**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{

    public function company(){

        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }

}
```

**boxesController.php (Controller)**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Box;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class boxesController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Box  $box
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Box $box)
    {        
        return view('boxes.show', compact('box'));
    }


}
```

**show.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout')


@section('title', 'Show Box')  


@section('content')

<h1 class="title">{{ $box->box_barcode }}</h1>

<p> <a href="/projects/{{$box->id}}/edit">Edit Box</a></p>

<h3 class="content">Status: {{ $box->box_quality }}</h3>

<hr>

<h5 class="content">List of Box Items:</h5>

<!-- ONLY SHOW TASK <DIV> IF A TASK EXISTS -->
@if ($box->items->count())
    <div>
        @foreach ($box->items as $item)

            <div>

                <form method="POST" action="/items/{{ $item->id }}">
                    @method('PATCH')
                    @csrf

                    <label class="checkbox {{ $item->in ? 'is-complete' : '' }}" for="in" >

                    <input type="checkbox" name="in" onChange="this.form.submit()" {{ $item->in ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                            {{ $item->box_id . ' ' .  $item->item_barcode . ' ' . $item->boxbarcode }}

                    </label>

                </form>         

            </div>

        @endforeach

    </div>
@endif

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Laravel Eagar Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) clause while retrieving specific relation based on the requirement like below:

```
public function show($boxId)
{
    $necessaryItemCheck = ['TRTB0001', 'TRTB0005'];
    //retriving related items
    $box = Box::with(['items' => function($itemQuery) use($necessaryItemCheck){

        //filtering items having boxBarCode required
        $itemQuery->whereIn('boxBarCode', $necessaryItemCheck);

    }])->where('id', $boxId)->first();
    return view('boxes.show', compact('box'));
}
```

It will return box with items having boxBarCode equals to **TRTB0001**.

You can simply use **whereIn** or **whereNotIn** based on your requirement

**EDIT 1**

If you wish to display the Item dynamically based on the user click, you need to pass the **boxBarCode** inside a href tag like:

```
//boxBarCode should be retrieved from database 
<a href="box/1?boxBarCode=TRTB0002">
```

Where you need to filter from boxBarCode = TRTB0002

```
public function show($boxId, Request $request)
{
    //retriving related items
    $box = Box::with(['items' => function($itemQuery) use($request){

        //filtering items having boxBarCode required
        $itemQuery->whereIn('boxBarCode', $request->boxBarCode);

    }])->where('id', $boxId)->first();
    return view('boxes.show', compact('box'));
}
```

Comment: If I need to avoid this issue with other boxBarCodes eg TRTB0002, how would I adjust this function?

Comment: I get the wrong results with TRTB0002. I probably should mention that the system works by clicking on a hyperlink in a page before eg TRTB0002 link that shows only the item_barcodes that belongs to it. etc TRTB0003 when someone clicks on its box link shows only the item_barcodes that belongs to it. etc

Comment: Edited the answer